# Scrape blockchain data into Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I’m trying to scrape some data in Google Sheets for the following page: https://mtvscout.com/token/0xa4b775e2563fa3a7f4d82ada9595383edc4bcb68/instance/20/token-transfers

The bit of information I need is the current owner of the token, that value is currently: 0x66762215c3F2FD42f2b2BD5AE905690e678aEc86

When I add "?type=JSON" to the end of the link, I can see that the data I require is under the "data-address-hash" tag. I would like to display that information in a cell of my Google Sheet but can’t seem to find a proper way to do this.  If there are multiple values for this tag, I only need the most recent one.

I included a Sheet where I tried IMPORTDATA. This fetches all information from the link and I then extract the bit that I need. This doesn’t seem to be an elegant solution. It takes very long to load information from only 300 links and my goal is 10000.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eNuB2Q2LE3iVuco7590z9hoF7CAVcHHDx25fr9nt4yI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

*(not an answer, but too long for a comment)*

Google Sheets is probably not the best tool to do that.

You may be able to implement the same a bit cleaner with `importxml()`, but it will probably not be practical do run imports from 10,000 different URLs in the same spreadsheet, regardless of which import function you are using.

As you add more rows, the spreadsheet is bound to get throttled, and you will start seeing more cells that show "Loading..."

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I was hoping to solve my problem with Sheets because other options need a server. No way around it I guess!